# JS: оптимальный вариант добавления пунктов списка, полученных с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript

Есть некий список HTML-элементов с общим родителем:

```
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Я получаю следующие пункты с помощью AJAX-запроса; они приходят как текст:

```
<div>...</div><div>...</div><div>...</div>
```

**Как наиболее правильно (и почему) их добавить в конец текущего списка**:

```
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
    <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
    <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
</div>
```

---

**1.** Взять `innerHTML` родителя (то есть уже существующие пункты), добавить к ним результат AJAX-запроса и впихнуть всё это в родитель:

```
parentOfItems.innerHTML = parentOfItems.innerHTML + responseText;
```

---

*Первый вариант вроде бы работал отлично, но при очередном его использовании на некотором проекте, где на родитель списка была навешана куча неких обработчиков, возникали дефекты; поэтому я начал искать альтернативные варианты реализации данной задумки; из этого, собственно, и возник данный вопрос.*

---

**2.** Создать строчную (`span`) обёртку, поместить в её `innerHTML` результат AJAX-запроса и добавить эту обёртку в родитель:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('span');

wrapper.innerHTML = responseText;

parentOfItems.appendChild( wrapper );
```

То есть результат получится следующий:

```
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <span>
        <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
        <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
        <div>...</div><!-- Новый пункт -->
    </span>
</div>
```

---

**3.** Создать *временную* обёртку, поместить в её `innerHTML` результат AJAX-запроса и добавить детей этой обёртки в родитель пунктов списка:

```
var tmpWrapper = document.createElement('div');

tmpWrapper.innerHTML = responseText;

for ( var i = 0; i < tmpWrapper.children.length; i++ ) {

    parentOfItems.appendChild( tmpWrapper.children[i] );

}
```

---

**4.** Только что пришёл в голову ещё один вариант: использовать JSON; то есть преобразовать на сервере выхлоп в JSON, а на клиенте распаковать его и просто перебрать пункты, добавляя их в родитель. Однако этот вариант мне кажется наиболее топорным.

Comment: какое именно значение хранится в response? добавьте пример

Comment: Да, покажите все-таки, как конкретно у вас данные прилетают.

К слову: каждый раз, когда Вы используете вагон дивов, там где по семантике надо использовать ul-li, в мире умирает один котенок и рождается один jQuery-программист.

Comment: @Grundy, это есть `responseText` — откорректировал вопрос.

Comment: @ru_volt, можно и списки, разницы нет,.. тогда 2 вариант отпадает. Ну и у каждого свои задачи; например, кому-то не нужна семантика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае стоит использовать функцию [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
var responseText = '<div>NEW1</div><div>NEW2</div><div>NEW3</div>';

document.getElementById('d').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',responseText);
```

```html
<div id="d">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

В первом варианте главный недостаток - пересоздаются элементы, которые уже были ранее. Отсюда весь набор "прелестей" - слетают обработчики событий, инвалидируются узлы дерева, падает производительность.

Второй вариант нарушает структуру.

Третий вариант лишен недостатков первых двух: разметка парсится всего один раз, старые элементы не трогаются, структура остается прежней.

Четвертый вариант вы зря называете "топорным" - он, как минимум, требует меньше сетевого трафика. Кроме того, он позволяет данные как-то обрабатывать, а не только вставлять. Но этот вариант требует нормального клиентского шаблонизатора, а они, в свою очередь, обычно тащат за собой целые фреймворки. Ключевые слова для гугления: AngularJS, KnockoutJS, React.

---

Ну а самый правильный вариант вам назвал Grundy

Comment: про третий пункт не понял, appendChild его сам вырежет и tmpWrapper, или не про то была речь? вернее не вырежет, а переместит

Comment: @Grundy хм, не знал...

Comment: Да, согласен с вами по поводу четвёртого варианта — это я поспешил с выводами.